# UI not updating document.getElementById("").textContent

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, getelementbyid, console.log

Posting this again because I did not have enough code posted before and the title was wrong. I created an object from a form that returns a grossIncome. In Js I have a function that will calculate the ei based on the gross income using 2 if statements and then updates it in the UI. When I console.log (), it appears to see the value and correctly, however the UI does not update.

index.html

```
<form name="formFill" id="form">
<input name="income" type="number" inputmode="numeric" id="incomeTextBox" placeholder="Gross Income" required> 
<select name="workingProvince" id="provinces">
<option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
<option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
...
</select>
<button type="submit" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div class="ei">
<h3>EI Deduction</h3>
<p id="eiValue">- $0</p>
</div>

<script type="module">
    import { submitForm } from './javascript/taxCalculatorIndex.js'
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', submitForm)
</script>
```

calculations.js

```
export const calculateEITax = (grossIncome) => {
        console.log ('calculateEITaxGross:', grossIncome)
    let ei;
    if (grossIncome <= 60300) {
        console.log ('grossIncome <= 60300:', grossIncome <= 60300)
        // console.log ('ei:', grossIncome * 0.0158 )
        ei = grossIncome * 0.0158;
    }
    else {
        ei = 60300 * 0.158;
    }
    return ei;
}
```

index.js

```
import {calculateEITax} from './calculations.js'


export const submitForm = (event) => {
event.preventDefault()
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const data = new FormData(form);
const dataObject = {};
for (const [key, value] of data.entries()) {
dataObject[key] = value;
};
let grossIncome = dataObject.income;
let province = dataObject.workingProvince;

calculateTax(grossIncome, province);
}
const calculateTax = (grossIncome, province) => {
const eiTax = calculateEITax(grossIncome);
    console.log("eiTax: ", eiTax)
 updateDOM(eiTax);
}
const updateDOM = (eiTax) => {
document.getElementById("eiValue").textContent = `- $${eiTax}`;
    console.log ("eiValue:", document.getElementById("eiValue").textContent = `- $${eiTax}` )
}
```

console.log output:

```
calculateEITaxGross: 30000
calculations.js:423 grossIncome <= 60300: true
index.js:95 eiTax:  474.00000000000006
index.js:127 eiValue: - $474.00000000000006
```

But my UI updates undefined

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Please don't repost your closed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348757/if-statement-ignoring-operators-in-js). Instead, edit the original question to include the information asked in the comments.

Comment: sorry about that. Someone closed my question so I wasnt able to continue in it